# Python User/Pass autofill selenium

Tags: python, selenium, browser, automation

I was following along with a tutorial to create the below program to
auto log into a github account. When I run the program it takes me to the sign in
page but does not not autofill the fields and submit. The tutorial was using "find_element_by_id" method. However, it was not recognized. After some googling I came up with the "By" class and it seems to work well earlier in the program when I used "By.LINK_TEXT" but fails when using it for .ID?
or maybe it is an issue with the "send_keys" method?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import re
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(
options=options, executable_path="C:\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://github.com")
signin_link = browser.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign in")
signin_link.click()

username_box = browser.find_element(By.ID, "login_field")
username_box.send_keys("username")
password_box = browser.find_element(By.ID, "password")
password_box.send_keys("password")
password_box.submit()
```

`

I tried the various constants for the By class (name, id, link_text, etc.)
None of them seems to make any difference. I imagine the problem is somewhere else in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Add `WebDriveWait` so the page can load before trying to pass the username and password

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(
options=options, executable_path="C:\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get("https://github.com")
signin_link = browser.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign in")
signin_link.click()

# wait until the page loads
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'login_field')))

username_box = browser.find_element(By.ID, "login_field")
username_box.send_keys("username")
password_box = browser.find_element(By.ID, "password")
password_box.send_keys("password")
password_box.submit()
```